# Upgrade to postgres version 14

Tags: postgresql

Can we upgrade directly from postgres version 10 to postgres version 14 with pg_upgrade. Is there any tool to determine if data storage format has changed with the new version.

Comment: [Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgupgrade.html) - pg_upgrade supports upgrades from 8.4.X and later to the current major release of PostgreSQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such tool, but the storage format hasn't changed, and you can use `pg_upgrade`.

The old and the new cluster must have the same encoding and locale, and the bootstrap superuser's name must be the same.  Block size, WAL segment size and  similar settings must be the same, and both must have data checksums on or off.